# How does NASA estimate the size of the population of Near-Earth Objects (NEO) of diameter>140 meters?

Tags: earth, near-earth-object, nasa

In 2018, the US Congress passed a bill to allocate budgets and mission goals to NASA.

[Section 321](https://www.congress.gov/115/bills/hr5503/BILLS-115hr5503rh.pdf) of that Bill mentions a goal for detection of NEOs of diameter >140 Km. Quote:

> (1) The George E. Brown, Jr. Near-Earth Object Survey Act (Public Law 109–155) established the Near-Earth Object Survey program to detect, track, and catalogue the physical characteristics of near-Earth objects equal to or greater than 140 meters in diameter in order to assess the threat of such objects to Earth.

> (2) The goal of the Survey program is to achieve 90 percent completion of the near-Earth project catalogue (based on statistically predicted populations of near-Earth objects) not later than 15 years after the date of the enactment of the George E. Brown, Jr. Near-Earth Object Survey Act.

I am interested in knowing (and possibly understanding) the methodology used to arrive at the "statistically predicted population(s)", without which Congress's goal (90% of the population) is a moving target.

Subsidiary: Is this methodology accepted by astronomers worldwide?

- EDIT1:

I am aware of the statistical technique called ["Mark & Recapture"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture), often used in wildlife studies. But I have doubts that it can be used for estimating the size of NEOs (of d=140m+). Asteroids do not "mix" back randomly in the population as fish would do in a pond.

Comment: @uhoh, you misunderstood. I was talking about the number. Congress said they wanted 90% of X to be catalogued by 2033 (2018+15). So, there is an agreed X. What is the methodology to get to that X.

Comment: oh, *that* size!

Comment: @uhoh, made the edit to clarify that's the size of the population. Note that the Bill also mentioned that only 30% of that overall population (d>140m) have been catalogued in 2018, in comparison to 90% of the population of (d>1Km).

Comment: Just a guess, but I'd say they inferred a probability distribution (probably something like Rosin-Rammler, often used for particle size distribution) from the bigger diameters, and extrapolated this distribution to estimate the population of smaller diameters.

Comment: @Jean-Marie Prival, that's another interesting approach. I guess the difficulty is to convince that the extrapolation to a larger population is justified. More or less the same statistical issue as "Tag & Recapture". We now have two candidate approaches. Progress!